# Configuring Varnish to read a header

Tags: varnish

I am using 3scale to manage the front end of any API. I want to include the API in the header of a request instead of the URL string (seems a little neater)

At the moment it gets defined as such.

```
  set req.http.X-3scale-app_id = regsub(req.url,".*[&?](app_id.[^&]*).*","\1");
  set req.http.X-3scale-app_key = regsub(req.url,".*[&?](app_key.[^&]*).*","\1");
  set req.http.X-3scale-user_key = regsub(req.url,".*[&?](user_key.[^&]*).*","\1");
  set req.http.X-3scale-user_id = regsub(req.url,".*[&?](user_id.[^&]*).*","\1");

  if (req.http.X-3scale-app_id != req.url) {
    set req.http.X-3scale-authrep = req.http.X-3scale-authrep + "&" + req.http.X-3scale-app_id;  
  }

  if (req.http.X-3scale-app_key != req.url ) {
    set req.http.X-3scale-authrep = req.http.X-3scale-authrep + "&" + req.http.X-3scale-app_key;  
  }

  if (req.http.X-3scale-user_id != req.url) {
    set req.http.X-3scale-authrep = req.http.X-3scale-authrep + "&" + req.http.X-3scale-user_id;  
  }

  if (req.http.X-3scale-user_key != req.url) {
    set req.http.X-3scale-authrep = req.http.X-3scale-authrep + "&" + req.http.X-3scale-user_key;  
  }

  unset req.http.X-3scale-app_id;
  unset req.http.X-3scale-app_key;
  unset req.http.X-3scale-user_id;
  unset req.http.X-3scale-user_key;
```

What I would like to do is take the key from the header because i think it seems better, so I could do something like...

set req.http.X-3scale-app_key = req.http.x-appid

However I can not get this to work! I am missing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use get method from vmod [header](https://github.com/varnish/libvmod-header) with something like this

```
set req.X-3scale-app_id = header.get(req.http.SomeOtherHeader,".*");
```

On client side you should set SomeOtherHeader in plaintext

But why you not set this X-3scale-app_id directly on client side?

Comment: it passes through 3scale for auth over api. I will try vmod header. How should the request look client side with that?